# Wipe 12.04/Windows 7 dual boot setup and start fresh new 12.04

Tags: 12.04, asus

I have an Asus u56e laptop running dual boot setup, Windows 7 and 12.04. I had Windows 7 first. I was wondering what's the easiest way possible to erase/format my drive (500GB) so that it deletes Ubuntu and Windows 7 so I can reinstall 12.04 onto my whole drive? Does the Ubuntu Live CD help make this a possibility or is there something with gparted I have to tinker with? I've already got everything I need backed up. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have Ubuntu anymore, or you can't find the installation CD, go to the Ubuntu website to [download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) Ubuntu. Choose the 32bit or 64bit version depending on your system. Burn the ISO to a CD.  Once that is done, boot from the newly created CD, make sure that you system is set to boot from CD.

When you get to the Installation Type screen, choose erase and install.

[image]

Continue the installation following the on screen instructions.

For more control over you disk, you can choose Something else.   and create an ext4 primary partition with the mount point / and leave some sapce to create a logical partition for swaparea.  The size of swaparea depends on the amount of RAM you have.  So I would say it would be safe to have 2GB of swap space.