# How to install Ubuntu on a zeroed-out drive?

Tags: system-installation

Very new at all of this...don't understand most of the answers I've read to other questions (i.e. partitions, iso images, etc.) BUT I zeroed-out my hard drive on a computer that ran XP and would like to download Ubuntu.

Can anyone explain how to do that in 'layman's' terms?

Comment: Have a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/158529/wipe-12-04-windows-7-dual-boot-setup-and-start-fresh-new-12-04/158540#158540

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu/145652#145652) for help. Skip steps 8 and 9, and only if it fails, try step 9, creating a new partition after invoking the `New partition table` command(skip the part with reducing old partitions). If you have trouble, feel free to comment(You may comment on answers to your questions, even with one reputation).

Comment: +1 but if I read the question right she wiped her drive already(zeroed??) and is starting out with a blank hard drive. Or at the very least wants to replace Windows completely. so she can skip steps 8 & 9 per this quote in step 8 `If you want to just clear out your hard disk, and use all of the space for Ubuntu, select that option, and skip to step 10`

Comment: @TrailRider I have seen automated partitioning fail miserably in VmWare. I will suggest it, though.

Comment: I have never used VMWare at all so I have to defer to you here.  I have used the installer to install Ubuntu as the only OS successfully. I was only commenting here as the question states that she was looking for a "laymans" answer and the extra step should not be needed if not dualbooting(i.e. I was trying to keep the answer good for a beginner, the thought of manual partitioning can scare a new user, I know it did me when I first tried Ubuntu)

Comment: @TrailRider OK, suggested.